# c# Regex capturing repeated keyword values

Tags: c#, regex, capture, repeat

I'm trying to capture the value of a keyword that is delimited by either another keyword or the end of the line with the keywords possibly be repeated, in any order or have no data to capture:

Keywords:
K1,K2

Input data:
somedatahereornotk1capturethis1k2capturethis2k2capturethis3k1k2

I want the captured data to be

```
1. capturethis1
2. capturethis2
3. capturethis3
4. 
5.
```

I've tried `k1|k2(?<Data>.*?)k1|k2`, but the captured data is always empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track with the alternations. The missing piece is to use look-behind and look-ahead to assert that something must be preceded and followed by the delimiters.

```
(?<=k1|k2)(?<Data>.*?)(?=k1|k2)
```

Lookbehind `(?<=…)` and lookahead `(?=…)` are zero-width assertions, so they must be satisfied but do not become part of the match.

Your desire to capture instances of consecutive delimeters is a bit trickier, because you can't really capture "nothing" -- the space between two characters. One approach would be to capture the lookbehind (or lookahead):

```
(?<=(?<Delimiter>k1|k2))(?<Data>.*?)(?=k1|k2)
```

This will yield 4 results instead of 3, because it will include the consecutive `k1k2` at the end of your sample data. You'll just have to ignore the extra data for each match (`k1`,`k2`,`k2`,`k1`).

Answer (score 3):

First, be aware that the alternation operator `|` has low precedence, so

```
k1|k2(?<Data>.*?)k1|k2
```

is actually looking for `k1` or `k2(?<Data>.*?)k1` or `k2`.  Use grouping:

```
(?:k1|k2)(?<Data>.*?)(?:k1|k2)
```

Second, consider using the zero-width lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
(?<=k1|k2)(?<Data>.*?)(?=k1|k2)
```

Comment: I tweaked it slightly to get the last capture delimited of end of line: (?<=k1|k2)(?<Data>.*?)(?=k1|k2|$), but other than that it was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

```
string s="somedatahereornotk1capturethis1k2capturethis2k2capturethis3k1k2";

Regex r=new Regex("(?<=k1|k2).*?(?=k1|k2)");
foreach(Match m in r.Matches(s))
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```